# EF Core: Child collection change detection in a disconnected environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

My backend is a Web API and frontend is an Angular app.

Our frontend allows a user to Edit multiple fields on the Parent object as well as a child collection in a single HTTP POST call to the API.

This is important because the user may delete several items from the collection, and then add new items to the collection, all during the same HTTP POST call to the API.

The call to the API to update the Parent object, sends an updated collection of items.

**Example**:

Frontend receives a collection { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

User deletes items 1, 2.

User adds item 6.

User clicks "Save" and sends a POST with the following collection: { 3, 4, 5, 6 }

**Question**:

Is there a built-in feature in EF Core, that allows it to detect which items are missing from the collection and which items are new to the collection so that it can SaveChanges appropriately?

```
public class Parent
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

// Repository - generic update method
public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
    }

    try
    {
        // HERE EF Core needs to identify be able to detect parent.Children collection changes. Which are new, which are dirty, which are marked for deletion.
        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return entity;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be updated: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

// Controller - update for Parent
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutParent(long id, ParentDto dto)
{
    if (id != parent.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    try
    {
        var parentEntity = mapper.Map<Parent>(dto);
        await Repository.UpdateAsync(parentEntity);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ParentExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```